# How to modify materialize css select option?

Tags: html, css, materialize

**EDIT**

I am trying to modify materialize select option's caret in such a way that that caret will go near to the horizontal line by modifying some default code, so from

```css
.select-wrapper .caret {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto 0;
    z-index: 0;
    fill: rgba(0,0,0,0.87);
}
```

to

```css
.select-wrapper .caret {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 15px;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto 0;
    z-index: 0;
    fill: rgba(0,0,0,0.87);
}
```

**top: 0; to top: 15px;**, If i modify it on chrome inspect element, it takes effect but on my customize css file there is no effect. I wonder why?

As for the HTML:

```
<div class="col s12 m8 l8">
    <select id="gender" name="gender_val">
        <option value="" disabled="" selected><< Pls select >></option>
        <option value="male">Male</option>
        <option value="female">Female</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

to where the `div tag` to be put is i really have no idea. I just saw this on the browser inspect element:

[image]

Here is the image of what i am referring.

[image]

Comment: please add html to your css so we can reproduce your behaviour.

Comment: I only did this:

```<div class="col s12 m8 l8">
<select id="gender" name="gender_val">              <option value="" disabled="" selected><< Pls select >></option>
<option value="male">Male</option>           <option value="female">Female</option>
</select>
</div>``` but i dont know where to put those css tag.

Comment: You also have some JS that generates the custom caret, please show this too.

Comment: If you're gonna use `!important` then it'll work

Comment: @cloned so far i did not make any JS on this part, unless i will modify the materialize.min.js file.

@GermaVinsmoke where should i put ```!important```?

Comment: maybe *you* didn't write the JS for the Dropdown but if you see your screenshot you will see that there is no select and no option, there is some ul that is generated by JS. So if we should help you we would also need to know which JS-Plugin you are using for selects.

Answer (score 2):

When you make the change in your CSS and inspect, do you see the change in the inspector?
If not, it's likely that Chrome's cache is bugging you...
In this case you can access in incognito mode and check if the change is displayed.